# C++ Variable contents being lost between 2 functions [Unreal]

Tags: c++

Greetings fellow programmers.

I've been struggeling with learning c++ within the Unreal engine. I thought I understood how to track time properly within a class but alas my variable is chaning it's contents to a vastly different number in the time between two function calls.

For context there are a small number of objects present:

- Global Time system

  - This class is responsible for managing the time and receiving update ticks from the time watcher. This is also a singleton!
- TimeWatcher

  - Super simple, just a Uobject I spawn into the world so it can receive update ticks from the engine and pass them onto the Global Time system
- Time class

  - A class to hold the hours, minutes and seconds. How it is used beyond that is up to the developer using the class. In my case I am simply trying to store it and from that point on remove time off of it to create a countdown timer.

We have our own little logging system to help debugging along, mainly to generate logs without all the unreal stuff and in a format we prefer. This log outputs the following data:

```
<Log, TimerSystem> [2] 2019.03.17-17.41.42: init attempt, init time should be: 23:6.0
<Log, TimerSystem> [3] 2019.03.17-17.41.42: init attempt succes, 23:6.0
<Log, TimerSystem> [6] 2019.03.17-17.41.42: Timer tick occured, lets see what our timer thinks about the time -225161083:32766:00
```

So from this we can interpret that the variable in the scope it gets set in(shown below) is set there properly. But the moment we try to read it again in the handleTick function the variable is all wrong.

InitTimer function:

```
void GlobalTimerSystem::InitTimer(UWorld* world, Time* initialTime)
{

    DebugUtility::WriteLog("init attempt, init time should be: " + initialTime->ToString(), DebugUtility::Log, DebugUtility::TimerSystem);
    check(world);

    //create timeWatcher in the world
    FVector location(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    FRotator rotation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;
    world->SpawnActor<ATimeWatcher>(location, rotation, SpawnInfo);
    //set current time to init value
    Time* trPointer = new Time(initialTime->GetHours(), initialTime->GetMinutes(), initialTime->GetSeconds());
    this->timeRemaining = *trPointer;
    DebugUtility::WriteLog("init attempt succes, " + timeRemaining.ToString(), DebugUtility::Log, DebugUtility::TimerSystem);
    }
```

There is some stupid pointer crap I am doing here, partly because of desperation at this point though.

The Handle tick function:

```
void GlobalTimerSystem::HandleTimerTick(float deltaTime)
{
    DebugUtility::WriteLog("Timer tick occured, lets see what our timer thinks about the time " + timeRemaining.ToString(), DebugUtility::Log, DebugUtility::TimerSystem);
    ticksReceived++;
    FString debug2;
    debug2.Append("Ticks received: ");
    debug2.AppendInt(ticksReceived);
    DebugUtility::WriteLog(debug2, DebugUtility::Log, DebugUtility::TimerSystem);
    double t = static_cast<double>(deltaTime);
    DecreaseTimer(&t);
    if (deltaTime != NULL) {
        FString debug;
        debug.Append(TEXT("current time remaining is "));
        debug.Append(*timeRemaining.ToString());
        DebugUtility::WriteLog(debug, DebugUtility::Log, DebugUtility::TimerSystem);
    }
}
```

Now we know things are already wrong the moment we enter the above function. For good measure here is the header file for this class.

```
class PGT_PROJECT_API GlobalTimerSystem
{
    friend class ATimeWatcher;
private:
    Time timeRemaining;
    Time timeElapsedNotPaused;
    Time timeElapsedPaused;
    UINT ticksReceived = 0;
    bool paused = false;
    bool initComplete = false;
    void HandleTimerTick(float deltaTime);
    static GlobalTimerSystem* timerSystem;

public:
    static GlobalTimerSystem* GetTimerSystem();

    void InitTimer(UWorld* world, Time* initialTime);
    void IncreaseTimer(double* additionalSeconds);
    void DecreaseTimer(double* removeSeconds);

    double GetTimeRemaining();
    double GetTimeElapsed();
    GlobalTimerSystem();
    ~GlobalTimerSystem();
};
```

If any more information is required I will be happy to provide. Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

I am overloading the Time::operator= which appears as follows:

```
Time & Time::operator=(Time & t)
{
    _seconds = t._seconds;
    _minutes = t._minutes;
    _hours = t._hours;
    return *this;
}
```

And using it as follows:

```
this->timeRemaining = Time(initialTime->GetHours(), initialTime->GetMinutes(), initialTime->GetSeconds());
```

However this results in the following compiler error that I do not understand:

```
Path...\Private\GlobalTimerSystem.cpp(62) : error C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 'Time' to 'Time &'
```

Comment: Is there something I'm overlooking or is there a serious type mismatch between `GlobalTimerSystem::timeRemaining` (of type `Time`) and `trPointer` (of type `Time*`) in the assignment `this->timeRemaining = trPointer;`? But I'm puzzled because this is the sort of thing the compiler would definitely complain about...

Comment: @PiCTo Hmm yea your right thats for sure incorrect. I've added a derference to it to see if behavior changed at all. Sadly, that is not where the error is. But thinking a bit further I overloaded the = operator to be able to do this. I've opted to remove the code and leave the derefernce. Things look better, however after init my timer which should say 23:6.0 reports back 0.0

Comment: Operator precedence: `*timeRemaining.ToString()` parses as `*(timeRemaining.ToString())`. So your `timeRemaining` is converted to a string, and then the `*` is applied, which presumably extracts the first character.

Comment: @RaymondChen I doubt that's the issue here. I am seeing it work properly on the first couple of runs where I know exactly what is in the variable.

Comment: @TDSrock A proper `operator=` should take a `const` parameter (here, `t`). Anyhow, if this is your overloaded `operator=`, it does nothing more than the _default_ `operator=` (_i.e._ a shallow copy) and you don't need it. Looking at the bigger picture, your design seems more complicated than it should be: you want to keep track of time and the simplest way to do so would be to have a single counter _e.g._ for seconds (hours and minutes can be converted to seconds). You then manipulate a single built-in type which will be much less error-prone for you, based on your current abilities in C++.

Comment: ... You then need to convert it to hours and minutes for the cases where you print it but this should be straightforward. If you have access to C++11 (and the Standard Library), [`std::chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) has everything you'd need (and more). Also, I would recommend you learn about _references_ as they were created to replace pointers in the C-like case in which you seem to use them! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In `GlobalTimerSystem::InitTimer(UWorld*, Time*)`, you do the following:

```
Time* trPointer = new Time(initialTime->GetHours(),
                           initialTime->GetMinutes(),
                           initialTime->GetSeconds());
this->timeRemaining = trPointer;
```

which means:

- Create a `new` object of type `Time` on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP), construct it with the following arguments and, once it's ready, return a pointer to it (`Time*`) which I'll store in my local variable `trPointer`;
- assign the value of the pointer `trPointer` (which is the **address** of the instance of the class `Time` that we just allocated and initialized on the heap) to my instance variable `timeRemaining` (which is an **instance** of the class `Time`).

So once you reach `GlobalTimerSystem::HandleTimerTick`, `this->timeRemaining` contains *garbage* which stays *garbage* when translated `ToString` (hence the `-225161083:32766:00` you see). Furthermore, the memory you now have allocated on the heap for that instance of `Time` you've created is wasted as you will never release it and won't even use it.

The thing is that, in this case, you don't need the heap at all!

Depending on how `operator=` behaves (you said you overloaded it), you should be able to do:

```
this->timeRemaining = Time(initialTime->GetHours(),
                           initialTime->GetMinutes(),
                           initialTime->GetSeconds());
```

which will create a temporary `Time` instance and initialize it with the passed arguments, then "copy" it (`=`) inside your instance variable `timeRemaining`. If you do this, you might want to look into `Time::operator=(Time&&)` as that "temporary `Time` instance" is an rvalue. Please note that, in this case, we do not leak memory as everything is allocated on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) and will be released when the function returns.

If this does not work, that means `Time::operator=` is not behaving as a proper "copy operator" and should be fixed. Another approach would be to manually set the hours, minutes and seconds fields of `timeRemaining` (if they are `public` or `friend`) or (much better), to have a method such as `Time::set(/*hours, minutes, seconds*/)` allowing you to `this->timeRemaining->set(...)`.

Finally, once again depending on the internals of `Time` and how `Time::operator=` has been written, noticing that `initialTime` is itself a `Time*`, the "temporary intermediate `Time` instance" shouldn't even be needed, leading to the much simpler and more readable

```
this->timeRemaining = *initialTime;
```

As a conclusion, I believe your issue comes from the implementation of `Time::operator=`.

Comment: You could be totally correct there that the problem is with my overload of the = operator.

Do you have any exampes of an = operator that is properly overloaded? I couldn't find any on the internet. (That I fully understood)

At the very least, thank you for the informative post This will probably lead me to the correct answer.

Comment: I have no experience with Unreal; Is `Time` your own class? If not, are you sure you have a good reason for overloading `Time::operator=`? If it is, adding (at least) its definition and your implementation of `operator=` would help.

Comment: I will add them to the post now. Time is my own class that is separate from Unreal. Unreal does have a TimeCode class that is similar to this but has some limitations which forced me to making my own.